# Empty DOM inside popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, popup

I have a popup window that must span multiple frames, so I'm using window.createPopup to get this to work. (IE6, 7, and 8.)

Below is the function I'm using to create the popup:

```
function ShowMyPopup() {
    notificationPopup = window.createPopup();
    $(notificationPopup.document.body).load("/notification.html");
    notificationPopup.show($(sourceFrame.document.body).width() - 510, $(sourceFrame.document.body).height() - (510 - $(sourceFrame.document.body).height()), 500, 500, sourceFrame.document.body);
}
```

This seems to work pretty well. I see the popup window as I should. The problem is, no matter what I do, I can't seem to access any of the DOM elements in the resulting popup window. I've tried various jQuery methods as well as a straight up getElementById, and all return NULL. Below is the contents of notification.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert($(document).html());
            alert($("#divNotification").html());
            alert(document.getElementById("divNotification"));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divNotification" onclick="$(this).toggle();">
        <h3>Some Notification!</h3>
        Testing 1234...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I see three alerts, so I know that jQuery is working, but all three alerts simply show "NULL". If I click on the resulting div, the onClick fires but I get an "Object Expected" error.

What is going on here?

Comment: In your demo, jQuery is not included.

Comment: You're trying to get the document's html by using '$(document).html()'. You should be using '("html").html()'. This is causing the first alert to return null. The other two may be caused by the DOM not being ready by the time you try to access it. Try adding a timeout to delay them.

Comment: Rob - jQuery is included in the parent page, which apparents allows it to work in the popup. (Or perhaps not?) At any rate, it makes no difference if I also add a script tag to ref jQuery in notification.html

Comment: Alex - your suggestion about using $("html").html() pointed me in the correction direction. Apparently, windows created with window.CreatePopup must be explicitly referenced even from inside their own content. Calling $("html").html() actually showed me the content of the source frame!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured this out. It's pretty counter intuitive.

Basically, I ended up loading all relevant javascript libraries into the source frame. I then must explicitly reference the source frame by its name in order to access these methods.

If any javascript - even javascript *inside* the popup window - wants to access the popup window's DOM, you must fully qualify it (or provide jQuery will the correct root object) for it to work.

For instance, here is my new notification.html:

```
<div id="divNotification" onclick="top.SourceFrame.MakePopupRed();">
    <h3>Some Notification!</h3>
    Testing 1234...
</div>
```

Now, in my source frame's referenced javascript library:

```
function MakePopupRed() {
    if (notificationPopup) {
        $("#divNotification", notificationPopup.document).css("background-color", "red");
    }
}
```

**So, basically, it appears that javascript that is run inside a popup created from window.createPopup executes in the context *of the parent window*, rather than the popup window itself!**

Comment: You're right, it's counter intuitive. Congrats on working it out. In practice, it should be easier to abstract the popup with eg. `var $nPopup = $("notificationPopup.document");` in each frame (as required) and to attach the popup's event handlers in javascript from there, using `$nPopup` as context. Attaching handlers in js  is generally better practice than the HTML approach PLUS, in this case, will avoid ever having to use the `top.SourceFrame. ...` notation in the popup to address js members in the regular frames.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this reference](http://javascript.gakaa.com/window-createpopup-4-0-5-.aspx), with `window.createPopup()` "scripts must assign content (not an external URL) to the popup object returned by the method".

If you want to assign content with an external URL then you need to use the non-proprietary (cross-browser) method [`window.open()`](http://javascript.gakaa.com/window-open-4-0-5-.aspx).

With `window.open()`, communication between the main window and the popup window can still be performed.

Assuming the popup to be opened with `var myPopup = window.open(...);`, then:

- Main window addresses popup as `myPopup`
- Popup addresses main window as `opener`

Comment: I am not assigning an external URL. I am loading the content from that external URL via jQuery, and assigning that content to the popup window.